# aws-load-balancer-controller deployment fails with "exceeded its progress deadline"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I am trying to figure out why my `aws-load-balancer-controller` deployment fails on EKS. When I run this command -`kubectl -n kube-system rollout status deployment aws-load-balancer-controller`

I get this error:

```
error: deployment "aws-load-balancer-controller" exceeded its progress deadline
```

This is my the response returned when I describe that deployment:

```
[ec2-user@myserver]$ kubectl describe deployment aws-load-balancer-controller -n kube-system
Name:                   aws-load-balancer-controller
Namespace:              kube-system
CreationTimestamp:      Mon, 18 Sep 2023 08:57:02 +0000
Labels:                 app.kubernetes.io/instance=aws-load-balancer-controller
                        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                        app.kubernetes.io/name=aws-load-balancer-controller
                        app.kubernetes.io/version=v2.6.0
                        helm.sh/chart=aws-load-balancer-controller-1.6.0
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 2
                        meta.helm.sh/release-name: aws-load-balancer-controller
                        meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: kube-system
Selector:               app.kubernetes.io/instance=aws-load-balancer-controller,app.kubernetes.io/name=aws-load-balancer-controller
Replicas:               2 desired | 0 updated | 0 total | 0 available | 3 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=aws-load-balancer-controller
                    app.kubernetes.io/name=aws-load-balancer-controller
  Annotations:      kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2023-09-18T09:17:49Z
                    prometheus.io/port: 8080
                    prometheus.io/scrape: true
  Service Account:  aws-load-balancer-controller
  Containers:
   aws-load-balancer-controller:
    Image:       public.ecr.aws/eks/aws-load-balancer-controller:v2.6.0
    Ports:       9443/TCP, 8080/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      --cluster-name=my-eks-cluster
      --ingress-class=alb
      --aws-region=us-east-1
      --aws-vpc-id=vpc-0df81666acdf1ba90
    Liveness:     http-get http://:61779/healthz delay=30s timeout=10s period=10s #success=1 #failure=2
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /tmp/k8s-webhook-server/serving-certs from cert (ro)
  Volumes:
   cert:
    Type:               Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:         aws-load-balancer-tls
    Optional:           false
  Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
Conditions:
  Type             Status  Reason
  ----             ------  ------
  Available        False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
  ReplicaFailure   True    FailedCreate
  Progressing      False   ProgressDeadlineExceeded
OldReplicaSets:    aws-load-balancer-controller-59bfbf77d9 (0/2 replicas created)
NewReplicaSet:     aws-load-balancer-controller-7dffbf659d (0/1 replicas created)
Events:            <none>
```

Note: there are no aws-load-balancer-controller pods running

I would appreciate some help, please. Can I check some other logs that could give me more insights on what went wrong with that deployment?

**UPDATE:**

After I've checked deployment on the AWS console, I noticed this section:

```
{
"type": "ReplicaFailure",
"status": "True",
"lastUpdateTime": "2023-09-19T14:50:08Z",
"lastTransitionTime": "2023-09-19T14:50:08Z",
"reason": "FailedCreate",
"message": "pods \"aws-load-balancer-controller-59bfbf77d9-\" is forbidden: error looking up service account kube-system/aws-load-balancer-controller: serviceaccount \"aws-load-balancer-controller\" not found"
}
```

It looks like the problem is to do with the aws-load-balancer-controller not being able to find its service account?

Comment: what is your eks version ?

Comment: Hi @Timam,  thank you for your comment. The version is 1.27. However, I've resolved the issue today and I added an answer to my own question. Appreciate you trying to help, thought :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned up to have to do with the eks_cluster terraform module that we are using from another team. It was creating the aws-load-balancer-conroller service account IAM Role using a shell script (via null_resource terraform resource). I recreated the cluster several times thinking it correctly deletes all of the resources. But of course not, TF doesn't know what the shell script does (that's why the use of null_resources should be avoided. So those dangling resources were screwing up the aws-load-balancer-conroller's service account deployment.

Lesson learned.